# A noun equivalent to "near absence"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun describing something that is present but rare. Specifically, I wish to say that a certain gene is almost never found in a group of species. Such a noun that could replace "**near-absence**" in the following sentence:

"The **near-absence** of the gene in X is intriguing given evidence for..."

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please explain why *near-absence* or *near-lack* are unsuitable, as these would be the shortest conventional ways to describe an almost total absence of something.

Comment: _Meagreness._ Lack of quantity or quality.

Comment: You are using 'lack' incorrectly and 'near lack' makes no sense. I suggest 'near absence' as an alternative to that.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome. I edited the question switching near lack to near absence. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK While not one word, "near absence" actually convey the meaning very well (as also noted in the answers of Graffito and R.S.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might [try](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=rarity)

> rarity ˈrɛːrɪti noun the state or quality of being rare.

scarcity is (in one possible meaning) a synonym of rarity, so that might also work.

Comment: The rarity/scarcity  may be emphasized by the adjective "extreme".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "**dearth**", which is defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dearth) as "the state or condition of not having enough of something".  One synonym might be "**paucity**".

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on a single-word noun.

dearth, paucity, infrequency, sparcity

EDIT

I see that Doug Warren has also suggested dearth.

Answer (score 0):

*Not really a single word*:

"The **near-total absence** of the gene in X is intriguing given evidence for..."

> Absence is the antonym of presence.

*EDIT: response provided before the replacement of "lack" by "absence" in the question*.

Answer (score 0):

It will be *nearly impossible* for any word to express the degree inherent in *near absence*.
Merriam-Webster online does say that  *INFINITESIMALITY* is a word, and it might be a probable in this case. But frankly, I've never read any author use this word and it would look odd .

I support the first commenter, that *near absence* is a perfectly fitting expression here.

Maybe *near-absence* (with a hyphen) can take over. It somehow looks more in place in a scientific paper, and is closer to being a single word.

Maybe some literary author   might have gotten away with *nigh absence*  too, but alas!